# VirtualBox on Win 7 Bridge Connection

Tags: virtualbox

I run a Win 7 host system with VirtualBox 4.2.10 installed. On VB, there is a CentOS 6.3 with an Apache. Now, from my VirtualBox I want to access the internet to use yum, wget aso. and from my host I want to reach my Apache instance. I think this setup is pretty common, but I can't find a way to figure it out correctly.

What might be of importance is that I use WLAN.

What I did is set my VB NIC to bridged with the name Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230. The adaptor type is Intel Pro/1000 MT Desktop (82540M). Promiscuous mode is on deny and the cable is connected.

In my global settings, I have a virtual network interface which is host only. I don't really get why. I dont' know how to configure this, but VB set the IP to 192.168.41.1 with DHCP deactivated. This NIC is also visible in my Win7 network configurations.

My CentOS eth0 has the static IP 192.168.56.2.

I cannot ping google.com from my VB. I cannot ping my VB from my host. Nothing is connected. Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like VirtualBox did not add an bridged adapter to my Win machine as it is ought to.

However, I solved it by configuring one VirtualBox adapter to use NAT and the other one to use host-only. Both use DHCP. My virtual network card is configured as host-only.

Now, I have two interfaces in linux. eth0 is the NAT one, which has an IP of 10.0.2.15 and eth1 (which I had to set up manually) has an IP of 192.168.56.101.